# sumifs 2 different tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 2 different tables, one containing the world's population per country over some years and the second the C02 emitted by the certain of those countries. I am looking to have the ratio of C02/pop in a third table. My problem is, the first table is shorter than the second table and the names are not in the same order. 
Here is a glimpse of the situation:

```
         Table1
country  2017 2018 2019     country  2017 2018 2019   
country1  xxx  xxx  xxx     country3  xxx  xxx  xxx
country2  xxx  xxx  xxx     country4  xxx  xxx  xxx
country3  xxx  xxx  xxx     country21 xxx  xxx  xxx
country4  xxx  xxx  xxx     country1  xxx  xxx  xxx
```

SO I only want to make that division if the countries match. I know I ca do it with a sumifs.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this solves your problem.

In the third table, country names are populated from the population (first) table of yours. And needed values are fetched with `VLOOKUP`s as seen in the in the image.

[image: emissions]